# Saving layer from OpenLayer 3 Map created by user

Tags: node.js, geojson, openlayers-3

I'm trying to correctly save an `OpenLayer 3 Map` layer created by a user in order to display it another map using `geoJSON`, but I'm having troubles with this.

On the **client** side I save the dinamic layer in this function:

```
function addInteractions() {                
    draw = new ol.interaction.Draw({
      source: source,
      type: typeSelect.value
    });
    draw.on("drawend", function(e) {
      var f = e.feature;
      features.push(f);
      geoJson = format.writeFeatures(features);
      console.log(geoJson);
      document.getElementById('js-textarea').value = geoJson;
    });
    map.addInteraction(draw);
    snap = new ol.interaction.Snap({source: source});
    map.addInteraction(snap);
}
```

Then the `geoJSON` object is saved into a `.json` file, but when I try to display it, it doesn't appear on the map.

Here his my display function:

```
var geoDataUrl = '/data/' + '{{percorso._id}}' + '.json';
var vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: new ol.source.Vector({
      url: geoDataUrl,
      format: new ol.format.GeoJSON()
    }),
    style: new ol.style.Style({
      fill: new ol.style.Fill({
        color: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2)'
      }),
      stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
        color: '#ffcc33',
        width: 2
      }),
      image: new ol.style.Circle({
        radius: 7,
        fill: new ol.style.Fill({
          color: '#ffcc33'
        })
      })
    })
  });       
  var raster = new ol.layer.Tile({
    source: new ol.source.OSM()
  });
  var map = new ol.Map({
    layers: [raster, vectorLayer],
    target: 'map',
    view: new ol.View({
      center: {{#if percorso.mapCenter}}[{{percorso.mapCenter}}] {{else}} ol.proj.transform([9.688053, 45.362760], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'){{/if}},
      zoom: {{#if percorso.zoomLevel}}{{percorso.zoomLevel}} {{else}} 13{{/if}}
    })
  });
```

I also tested the display function with other layers (for example the [provided one](https://openlayers.org/en/v4.6.4/examples/data/geojson/countries.geojson) on the OpenLayer examples website ) and it works fine

On the **server** side I save the `geoJSON`object with this function, where `oggetto_mappa` is the dinamic `geoJSON` object:

```
var jsonMappa = JSON.stringify(eval("(" + oggetto_mappa + ")"));
require("fs").writeFile("./public/data/" + id_perc + ".json", jsonMappa, 'utf8', function(f_err) {
     if(f_err)
       console.log(f_err);
});
```

For refernce this is what my function saves onto the `.json` file:

```
{
"type":"FeatureCollection",
"features":[
    {
        "type":"Feature",
        "id" : "aa",
        "geometry":
        {
            "type":"LineString",
            "coordinates":[
                [1073328.751180445,5680150.227413875],
                [1077857.6451063417,5682481.556776573],
                [1070385.9255914658,5679156.546046168],
                [1076825.7452244917,5680226.66444216],
                [1073328.751180445,5680169.336670946]
            ]
        },
        "properties":null
    },
    {
        "type":"Feature",
        "id" : "ab",
        "geometry":
        {
            "type":"LineString",
            "coordinates":[
                [1073328.751180445,5680169.336670946],
                [1071628.0273010998,5677130.96479661]
            ]
        },
        "properties":null}
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get things working, replace

```
geoJson = format.writeFeatures(features)
```

with

```
geoJson = format.writeFeatures(features, {featureProjection: 'EPSG:3857'})
```

You may wonder why?

When you draw in OpenLayers, you are drawing in the projection of the map (the default is EPSG:3857) whereas when you consume a GeoJSON the expected projection is EPSG:4326.

See [the API documentation](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.format.GeoJSON.html#writeFeatures) from `ol.format.GeoJSON` `writeFeatures` to understand better

***Some additional informations:***

- when you consume the GeoJSON from your drawing as the coordinates are not in decimal degrees (EPSG:4326) but in meters (EPSG:3857)
- the order of magnitude for coordinates is different (millions for EPSG:3857 and less than some hundred for EPSG:4326) without accounting for the positive/negative coordinates